# My proof ɛ-δ Definition of a limit only disproves the limit... What have I done wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Whilst attempting to prove that
$$\lim_{x\to8} \sqrt[3]{(3x+3)} = 3 $$ 
I came up with the following as my proof:
$$\lim_{x\to8} \sqrt[3]{(3x+3)} = 3 ⇔ (∀ε>0)(∃δ>0)(∀x)|x-8|<δ⇒|\sqrt[3]{(3x+3)}-\sqrt[3]{(27)}|≤ε⇒$$
$$|\sqrt[3]{(3x-24)}|≤ε⇒|\sqrt[3]{(3(x-8))}|≤ε∴|\sqrt[3]{(3δ)}|≤ε□$$
But that's when I realized that even though 
$$If δ=9, \;then \;ε≥3∵(f(x_{0}-δ)≤y_{0}-ε)$$
that
$$If δ=9, \;then \;ε≥3※∵¬(f(x_{0}+δ)≤y_{0}+ε)$$
and thus my proof falls apart. Where did I make a mistake? (or maybe I am misunderstanding, and my proof is correct?)

Thank you in advance!

Note: I am not 100% certain that I used all of these mathematical symbols correctly...

**EDIT:** Thanks to the comments that the wonderful people of math.stackexchange.com have provided below, I have concluded that
$$|\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b}| ≠ |\sqrt[3]{(a-b)}|$$
Even so, the expression **could** be true, but they are not **always** equal. Therefore, I must re-evaluate this problem, and I will update this question if I find another (correct) solution.

If anyone knows how to find the correct proof, please let me know what it is!

Thank you!

**SECOND EDIT:** I have refined my proof to this:
$$\lim_{x\to8} \sqrt[3]{(3x+3)} = 3 ⇔ (∀ε>0)(∃δ>0)(∀x)|x-8|<δ⇒|\sqrt[3]{(3x+3)}-\sqrt[3]{(27)}|≤ε⇒$$
$$|\sqrt[3]{(3x-24)}-\sqrt[3]{27}+\sqrt[3]{27}|≤ε⇒|\sqrt[3]{(3x-24)}|≤ε⇒$$
$$|\sqrt[3]{(3(x-8))}|≤ε∴|\sqrt[3]{(3δ)}|≤ε□$$
Yet I come out to the same answer. Unless 
$$\sqrt[3]{(3x+3)}-\sqrt[3]{27} ≠ \sqrt[3]{3x+3}-\sqrt[3]{27}+\sqrt[3]{27}$$
I have no idea what's **still** wrong about it!

Again, thank you for helping!

**THIRD EDIT:** I figured it out! The attempt above has the same problem as the first, I just made the mistake in a different way. Here's the **real** answer, which **actually** works.
$$\lim_{x\to8} \sqrt[3]{(3x+3)} = 3 ⇔ (∀ε>0)(∃δ>0)(∀x)|x-8|<δ⇒|\sqrt[3]{(3x+3)}-3|≤ε⇒$$
$$|\sqrt[3]{3x-24+27}-3|≤ε⇒|\sqrt[3]{3(x-8)+27}-3|≤ε∴\sqrt[3]{3δ+27}-3≤ε□$$
And that's it! It works! Thank you!

Comment: Are you really sure that $\sqrt[3]{a} - \sqrt[3]{b} = \sqrt[3]{a-b}$?

Comment: @Umberto: to be fair, the proof does not assume that. Rather, it assumes that if $|\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b}|<\epsilon$, then $|\sqrt[3]{a-b}|<\epsilon$. Obviously it is likely OP made the mistake you suggest, but it is not necessarily so.

Comment: I'm willing to throw caution to the wind and assume that it is.

Comment: Just saying it might be instructive for a student to be told exactly what assumption is being made....

Comment: You still seem to be using that $\sqrt[3]{3x+3}-\sqrt[3]{27}=\sqrt[3]{3x-24}$.

Comment: Uh... yeah, I guess I am... sort of. Look at that. Let me re-evaluate one more time and I'll see what I can do! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Argh! I seem to be only capable of coming up with proofs that lead to the same end problem! This is really getting to me! I MUST KNOW

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments,

your mistake was in going from $|\sqrt[3]{3x+3}-\sqrt[3]{27}|\le\epsilon$ to $|\sqrt[3]{3x-24}|\le\epsilon$.

---

One way to find a $\delta$ that will work for a given $\epsilon>0$ is to use

$\displaystyle\sqrt[3]{A}-\sqrt[3]{B}=\frac{A-B}{A^{2/3}+A^{1/3}B^{1/3}+B^{2/3}}\;\;$ with $A=3x+3$ and $B=27$

This gives $\displaystyle\big|\sqrt[3]{3x+3}-3\big|=\left|\frac{3x-24}{(3x+3)^{2/3}+(3x+3)^{1/3}3^{1/3}+3^{2/3}}\right|=\frac{3|x-8|}{|(3x+3)^{2/3}+(3x+3)^{1/3}3^{1/3}+3^{2/3}|}$.

If we choose $\delta\le9$, then $|x-8|<\delta\implies x>-1\implies 3x+3>0$,

so then $\displaystyle\big|\sqrt[3]{3x+3}-3\big|<\frac{3|x-8|}{3^{2/3}}<3|x-8|$.
 Therefore we also need to choose $\delta$ so that $3\delta<\epsilon$.

---

An alternate approach would be to use

$\big|\sqrt[3]{3x+3}-3\big|<\epsilon\iff3-\epsilon<\sqrt[3]{3x+3}<3+\epsilon\iff (3-\epsilon)^3<3x+3<(3+\epsilon)^3\iff$

$27-27\epsilon+9\epsilon^2-\epsilon^3<3x+3<27+27\epsilon+9\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3\iff$

$24-27\epsilon+9\epsilon^2-\epsilon^3<3x<24+27\epsilon+9\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3\iff$

$8-9\epsilon+3\epsilon^2-\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}<x<8+9\epsilon+3\epsilon^2+\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}$

Now if we let $d_1=8-(8-9\epsilon+3\epsilon^2-\frac{\epsilon^3}{3})=9\epsilon-3\epsilon^2+\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}$

$\hspace{.6 in}$and $d_2=(8+9\epsilon+3\epsilon^2+\frac{\epsilon^3}{3})-8=9\epsilon+3\epsilon^2+\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}$,

then we can check that $d_2>d_1>0$; so letting $\delta=d_1=9\epsilon-3\epsilon^2+\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}$

gives a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-8|<\delta\implies |\sqrt[3]{3x+3}-3|<\epsilon$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand entirely. I realize that that is how you would do a cube root minus another (different) cube root, but I don't see how that helps in this specific problem. The value of the first part with A=3x+3 and B=27 comes out to be x=8. Not sure how to use that, to be honest. Also, the second part only compares ϵ with x, rather than ϵ with δ. Could you possibly provide a complete proof of this limit? Thank you, and sorry for being so clueless.

Comment: I will edit my answer to supply more information (but I will leave part of it for you to do).

Comment: I'm so sorry, but in the first explanation, I understood everything up until the point where you simply got rid of the 3^(2/3) in the denominator of the last line to get < 3|x-8|. Plus, for δ=9, 3δ<ϵ would come out to have the same problem, as ϵ would still equal 3. In the second one, however, I do not understand the last part of the first line, and you seem to be veering over to δ<(ϵ^3)/3-3ϵ^2+9ϵ, which is completely different, still, if δ=9, ϵ still equals 3! I must be misunderstanding this completely... I haven't had such a hard time proving limits since I first learned to!

Comment: In the first explanation, I was using that $3^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{9}>1$ to get rid of $3^{2/3}$ in the denominator.  Then we end up with two conditions for $\delta$: we want  $\delta\le9$ and $3\delta\le\epsilon$, so we can take $\delta$ to be the minimum of $\{9, \frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$.  (I will add some explanation to the second approach.)

Comment: But wouldn't the fact that 3^(2/3) is greater than one (it's 2.08...) not mean that it IS one? Basically, I'm pretty sure that the top still has to be divided by 2.08... also, isn't the point of proving this so that we can find an expression in terms of delta that will be less than or equal to epsilon that will work for any value of delta? In other words, delta itself doesn't need to have a set value, other than for testing the final answer...? I'm not sure how the cuberoot is affecting this problem, but I'm having a difficult time understanding your explanation.

Comment: Yes, you're right -- I'm using $\frac{a}{3^{2/3}}<a$ since $3^{2/3}>1$, to make the inequality simpler to work with.  See if you can use the work given to show that if $0<|x-8|<\delta$, where $\delta=min\{9,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$, then $|\sqrt[3]{3x+3}-3|<\epsilon$  (I think the second approach is a little easier to understand, though.)

Comment: Hmm... the only problem that I see with that is that it changes the actual value of the expression, and your end answer of 3 delta = epsilon has the same problem!